# How to convert string contains multi-row to map

Tags: flutter, dart

I am reading a text file consisting of several lines, each line contains two numbers, one of them expresses the user name and the other expresses the password, the text appears as follows:

```
7829-613
2076-386
3001-007
5916-477
9782-858
3928-345
3574-189
```

I changed `-` to `:` by this code:

```
text= text.replaceAll('-', ':');
```

The result is :

```
7829:613
2076:386
3001:007
5916:477
9782:858
3928:345
3574:189
```

I tried to replace `\n` to `,` by this code:

```
text= text.replaceAll('-', ':')..replaceAll('\n',',');
```

So that I can separate each line, **key** and **value**, but not work

Is there any way to get `Map`from this `text`

**Thanks advance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  var text = "7829-613\n2076-386\n3001-007\n5916-477\n9782-858\n3928-345\n3574-189";
  text = text.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r"[0-9]{3,4}"), (match) => "\"${match.group(0)}\"");
  text = text.replaceAll("-", ":");
  text = text.replaceAll("\n", ",");
  var map = jsonDecode("{$text}");
  print(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `r` before to the `String` to read raw special characters.

```
String text = r'mmmmm\nssdsds\n';
text = text.replaceAll(r'\n', ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you open your file, you can declare `final credentials = Map<String, dynamic>`.

Then, you can iterate through each line of the file with an input stream as in https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-io/File-class.html.

That is the following, where in each line you split the string by the colon(:) separator and assign those key value pairs to the map:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

main() {
  final credentials = Map<String, dynamic>
  final file = new File('file.txt');
  Stream<List<int>> inputStream = file.openRead();

  inputStream
    .transform(utf8.decoder)       // Decode bytes to UTF-8.
    .transform(new LineSplitter()) // Convert stream to individual lines.
    .listen((String line) {        // Process results.
        final decodedLine = line.split(":");
        credentials[decodedLine[0]] = credentials[decodedLine[1]];
      },
      onDone: () { print('File is now closed.'); },
      onError: (e) { print(e.toString()); });
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions about this. I tried to be as thorough as I could :)